# Supervisor setup on laravel error can't find command 'php'

Tags: laravel-5, lamp, bitnami

I am setup a Supervisor Configuration on my bitnami LAMP server but when I am ruining sudo supervisorctl error coming 'laravel_queue:laravel_queue_00   FATAL     can't find command 'php''

My supervisor .conf file

```
'[program:laravel_queue]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /opt/bitnami/..../public/artisan queue:work --tries=1
directory=/opt/bitnami/...../public
startsecs = 0
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stderr_logfile=/opt/bitnami/..../public/storage/logs/laraqueue.err.log
stdout_logfile=/opt/bitnami/...../public/storage/logs/laraqueue.out.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB'
```

As a newbies please suggest how to debug this issue.

when run php artisan queue:work on my web root found permission error so change the permission as per requirement & command running smoothy.